# Given a set of strings, find an optimal lexicon which can be used to build those strings

Tags: string, algorithm, np-hard

Imagine I have a set of strings, for example:

```
"entrance",
"scent",
"transcend".
```

I would like to find an optimal "lexicon" of sub-strings which can be used to build the initial strings. The criterion is the smallest amount of memory needed to store both the lexicon and the strings using that lexicon.

For instance, for the given set of strings, the optimal lexicon of sub-strings may be:

```
"scen" = 1,
"tran" = 2,
"en" = 3,
"ce" = 4,
"t" = 5,
"d" = 6
```

with the initial set of strings encoded the following way (each `\N` represents a reference to the string N from the lexicon):

```
\3\2\4
\1\5
\2\1\6
```

for the total of 8 references used to build the strings + 14 chars needed to store the lexicon, versus the 22 chars in the original strings + 8 chars comprising the original alphabet. If you need an exact formula for the footprint, assume that `sizeof( reference ) == sizeof( char )`, and the footprint of a single string (both encoded and in lexicon) is `length of string * sizeof( char or reference )`, with no additional overhead.

What is the best algorithm to solve this problem? Does this algorithm have an established name? Is it NP-hard? If so, is there a sub-optimal, but polynomial solution?

**EDIT**: The best solution I could come up with is the following: find the longest common sub-string in the initial set of strings. Let the score for that sub-string be `(substring_length - 1) * total_occurrences_of_it_in_the_set - substring_length`, accounting for the number of chars/refs saved by that replacement. Now find all the smaller sub-strings (up until the length of 2) and calculate their scores the same way. Among all the sub-strings found this way, a sub-string with the largest score wins and gets into the lexicon. The sub-string is then replaced in the initial set of strings by the references to it, and the process repeats until our set of strings only contains single chars and lexicon references. After that, introduce all the remaining single chars into the lexicon and replace them with their references in the set. The explanation of the scoring is the following: we remove `substring_length` chars from each occurrence, add a reference instead (hence `-1`), and need `substring_length` chars to store the sub-string (hence `-substring_length`).

Any better approach you can think of?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Is it the required output format (which I'm not clear on) that makes this different from just general compression?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I can only think of a complete brute-force for the optimal solution, which doesn't seem realistic. There may be a greedy solution here (find the longest common sub-string, put it into lexicon and replace all occurrences, repeat until there are no chars left), but I would expect it to be quite sub-optimal (e.g. two long enough similar strings are enough to introduce a new lexicon entry).

Comment: By the way, if you want a more general algorithmic answer you should probably post this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the exact output format does not matter, though the idea is that the lexicon is fixed (and the set of strings is fixed, too). This is a bit different from the general compression - for instance, it allows for random access to the strings among other things. So no, I'm not looking for just any compression scheme, but rather for the solution to the exact posted problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: updated the question with the best solution I could come up with.